# Animating Three.js vertices

Tags: animation, three.js, position, vertices

I'm trying to animate individual vertices from a collada model.
The vertices ARE animating fine once but then they don't animate anymore.

1: Load my collada

```
// name obj
var orgVerts = false;
var desVerts = false;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0x1e5679, wireframe:true });
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var nameModel = false;

loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( '3d/name.dae', function ( collada ) {
    nameModel = collada.scene.children[0].children[0];
    nameModel.material = material;
    nameModel.geometry.dynamic = true;
    nameModel.position.set(0,0,0);//x,z,y- if you think in blender dimensions ;)
    nameModel.scale.x = .0035;
    nameModel.scale.y = .0035;
    nameModel.scale.z = .0035;
    scene.add(nameModel);
    orgVerts = nameModel.geometry.vertices; // make a backup of all verts
    genVerts(); // create a new array of random verts
});
```

2: in my render function

```
var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    // do stuff
    if(nameModel){
        if(window.globalCurrentSlide != 0){
            for(var r=0; r < nameModel.geometry.vertices.length; r++){
                var vert = desVerts[r]; // loop through all the destination verts
                nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].x = nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].x - (nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].x - vert.x)/20;
                nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].y = nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].y - (nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].y - vert.y)/20;
                nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].z = nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].z - (nameModel.geometry.vertices[r].z - vert.z)/20;
            }
        }else{
            for(var t=0; t < nameModel.geometry.vertices.length; t++){
                var vert2 = orgVerts[t]; // loop through all the original verts
                nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].x = nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].x - (nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].x - vert2.x)/20;
                nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].y = nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].y - (nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].y - vert2.y)/20;
                nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].z = nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].z - (nameModel.geometry.vertices[t].z - vert2.z)/20;
            }
        }
        nameModel.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        nameModel.rotation.y += .005;
    }
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

`window.globalCurrentSlide` is set to 0 to start with and everything is fine. if I change `window.globalCurrentSlide` to 1, all the vertices animate correctly... **BUT** when I change `window.globalCurrentSlide` back to 0 the vertices don't animate back to their original positions. I've debugged heaps and can 100% say that **BOTH** `desVerts` and `orgVerts` don't change and they are correct. Any ideas? It's driving me nuts.

PS: I know the code could be condensed, I'm just playing ATM

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that my `orgVerts` was just a reference NOT a clone. use:

```
var geometry = nameModel.geometry.clone();
orgVerts = geometry.vertices;
```